# Bamboo Junit Test Parser For Android Project

Tags: android, bamboo

I'm trying to introduce CI for my Android project, Download the trial version of bamboo server for windows [Installation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/installing-bamboo-on-windows-289276813.html).

Added Script task to compile the project 
"./gradlew assembleDebug test"

I want to show the Junit Test Result, I added the Junit Test Parser with below configuration

```
 Specify custom results directories
**/test-results/debug/*.xml
```

Getting following error in console and build fail

```
    \bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\COL-CI-JOB1>./gradlew assembleDebug test 
18-Jul-2017 22:58:51    Could not load Logmanager "org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager"
18-Jul-2017 22:58:51    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
18-Jul-2017 22:58:51            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
18-Jul-2017 22:58:51            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
18-Jul-2017 22:58:51            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
18-Jul-2017 22:58:51            at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:195)
18-Jul-2017 22:58:51            at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:181)
18-Jul-2017 22:58:51            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
18-Jul-2017 22:58:51            at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:181)
18-Jul-2017 22:58:51            at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:448)
```

Comment: I suggest googling the error message. Most likely someone else has already encountered this problem and found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

May be this help to someone:
More information in this [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamkb/junit-parser-test-results-are-not-found-376833568.html)

Check the JUnit task configuration and confirm that you have configured it to look for the test results file in the current working directory of your job: /home/bamboo/home/xml-data/build-dir/CLX-BUILD-TEST, not in a subdirectory like: /home/bamboo/home/xml-data/build-dir/CLX-BUILD-TEST/test-reports.

[Referecnce](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/junit-parser-289277056.html?_ga=2.15212150.137097631.1500368611-1322629984.1499771464)

```
set the Junit Test Result Path 
Specify custom results directories
/**app/**/test-results/**/*.xml

Advanced options
checked "Pick up test results that were created outside of this build"
```